# DELL PowerEdge T110 - Unable to connect to Postgres Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server

i've just bought a **DELL PowerEdge T110 II** with **Microsoft Windows Small Business Server 2011**.

I've installed PostgreSQL (latest version 9.1) and i've made the pg_hba configuration for access the DB from other LAN PC.

Here is my problem, if i try to connect to PGServer with PGAdmin from LAN PC quickly after the bootup of the server i can connect without problems.

After few minutes (2-3) i cannot connect anymore to the PGServer. If i connect to the server with PGAdmin local there is no problem and only after that i can successfully connect to the PGServer w/o problems.
Another solution is to remove the LAN Cable from the server and plug-in again. In this way the PGAdmin from other LAN PC gets back to work.

Here the message i get

> Server doesn't listen
>   The server doesn't accept connections: the connection library reports 
>   could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "192.168.4.10" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Is some sort of standby of the Postgres process?

(I know my english is not wonderful, if you don't understand something, ask and i'll explain better)

Edit:  The same thing happens with remote desktop so this does not seem to be a PostgreSQL issue.

Comment: This question should be on SuperUser

Comment: Looks like a network issue, not a PostgreSQL problem. Did you check the firewall?

Comment: @FrankHeikens: Sure, all the 3 firewalls are disabled. Also the power save is set to 30mins.
I have the same issue with Remote Desktop so i think you're right, it's not a PG problem

Comment: @DevilingMaster Mind closing the question then? Maybe post a more generic one with more detail (traceroute / ping data, etc) on superuser?